# How do isomorphisms determine equivalence relations on the class of all groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-isomorphism

> Let $\phi:G_{1}\to G_{2}$ and $\psi:G_{2} \to G_{3}$ be isomorphisms and assume that $\phi ^{-1}$ and $\psi \circ \phi$ are isomorphisms. Show that the isomorphism of groups determines an equivalence relation on the class of all groups.

Is it sufficient to just say that $\phi ^{-1}$ represents symmetry and $\psi \circ \phi$ represents transitivity? Then what about reflexivity? Is the identity function an isomorphism?

Comment: Its always nice to use the word "because". $\phi^{-1}$ represents symmetry; this exists because isomorphisms are invertible. And so on.

Comment: I think your phrasing is particularly apt - much cleaner than a more formal proof. I hope your instructor agrees (if this is part of an assignment).

Comment: Wait...I just re-read your post - the assumption on $\phi^{-1}$ and $\phi\circ\psi$ are irrelevant! They are isomorphisms as $\phi$ and $\psi$ are isomorphisms...

Comment: @user1729 Part of the question was to show that $\phi ^{-1}$ and $\psi \circ \phi$ (typo in question) are isomorphisms. Then use those results to show they determine an equivalence relation.

Comment: @krirkrirk Sorry, I made a typo in the order...

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x)$ does not necessarily mean $f(g(x))$; some people (myself included) write $(f\circ g)(x)$ to mean $g(f(x))$. This has certain benefits (when you read left-to-right, the first function that you see is the first function that you apply). However, you should be aware that notation is, in general, ambiguous. Your use was without ambiguity though (while $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ would not make sense!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the $id:G \to G$ s.t $id(g)=g; \forall g \in G$ gives you the reflexivity.

Comment: Do you mean $G_{1}$? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Yes, you can take it as any group $G$. You can accept my answer if you are satisfied.